# Python Binary File Manipulation Speed Up

Tags: python, file-io, binary

I am using python to read mass amounts of data and split them into various files.  I am looking for a way to speed up the code that I already have.  The numbers coming in are little-endian 32bit floats.  I have run several tests.

First test 8 minutes to complete:

```
f = open('filename','rb')
#file_out is a list of many open writing files 'wb'
while chunk:
    for i in range(self.num_files):
        chunk = f.read(4)
        file_out[i].write(chunk)
```

This was acceptably fast, but when I try to add some operations, things slow down dramatically to 56 minutes:

```
file_old = [0,0,0,...,0]
f = open('filename','rb')
#file_out is a list of many open writing files 'wb'
while chunk:
    for i in range(self.num_files):
        chunk = f.read(4)
        num_chunk = numpy.fromstring(chunk, dtype = numpy.float32)

        file_out[i].write(num_chunk-file_old[i])
        file_old[i] = num_chunk
```

I ran cProfile on the above code on a shortened sample.  Here are the results:

write = 3.457

Numpy fromstring = 2.274

read = 1.370

How could I speed this up?

Comment: How do we know what the slowest part is? You should use a profiler to determine whether it's numpy or whether it's something else.

Comment: I added some basic cProfile info above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to discover a much faster way of reading in the data using `numpy.fromfile`.  I wrote a quick little test script shown below:

```
from os.path import join
import numpy
import struct
from time import time


def main():

    #Set the path name and filename
    folder = join("Tone_Tests","1khz_10ns_0907153323")
    fn = join(folder,"Channel1.raw32")


    #Test 1
    start = time()
    f = open(fn,'rb')
    array = read_fromstring(f)
    f.close()
    print "Test fromString = ",time()-start
    del array

    #Test 2
    start = time()
    f = open(fn,'rb')
    array = read_struct(f)
    f.close()
    print "Test fromStruct = ",time()-start
    del array

    #Test 3
    start = time()
    f = open(fn,'rb')
    array = read_fromfile(f)
    f.close()
    print "Test fromfile = ",time()-start
    del array


def read_fromstring(f):
    #Use Numpy fromstring, read each 4 bytes, convert, store in list
    data = []

    chunk = f.read(4)

    while chunk:
        num_chunk = numpy.fromstring(chunk, dtype = 'float32')
        data.append(num_chunk)

        chunk = f.read(4)

    return numpy.array(data)

def read_struct(f):
    #Same as numpy froms string but using the struct.
    data = []

    chunk = f.read(4)

    while chunk:
        num_chunk = struct.unpack('<f',chunk)
        data.append(num_chunk)

        chunk = f.read(4)

    return numpy.array(data)

def read_fromfile(f):
    return numpy.fromfile(f, dtype = 'float32', count = -1)
```

The timed outputs from the terminal were:

```
Test fromString =  4.43499994278
Test fromStruct =  2.42199993134
Test fromfile =  0.00399994850159
```

Using `python -m cProfile -s time filename.py > profile.txt` shows that the times were:

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.456    1.456    4.272    4.272 Read_Data_tester.py:42(read_fromstring)
        1    1.162    1.162    2.369    2.369 Read_Data_tester.py:56(read_struct)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.005 Read_Data_tester.py:70(read_fromfile)
```

Comment: If you want to avoid using numpy for some reason (I use it all the time, but it's not installed everywhere) you can also use the builtin array.array type do do similar things http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html This type only supports 1d  arrays, without the mathematical ops that numpy has; but it supports some list operations (like append()) which numpy does not. And it has a .fromfile method. With array.array, you need to create an empty array of the desired numeric type, and then use .fromfile to load it with data.

Answer (score -2):

I think you may be able to make use of threading (using the threading module).

This will alow you to run functions in parralel with your main code therefore you could start one a third of the way through the file, another halfway and another threequarters the way through. There fore each only has to process a quater of the data and so it *should* take only a quater of the time.

(I say should as there is overhead so wont be quite that fast)

Comment: The order of the data matters within each channel.  The give relative changes thus the new value - old value.

Comment: Ah yeah :/ Bit slow today :/